# How to implement function to wrap Iterator and ExactSizeIterator in different ways

Tags: rust, traits

I'm attempting to teach myself some Rust, so my first idea was to create a wrapper to `Iterator`s that can 'automagically' log the current progress, if given an 'output stream'.

I came up with this basic `wrap(..)` function:

```rust
pub fn wrap<T, W, I>(iterable: T, output_stream: W) -> impl Iterator
where
    T: IntoIterator,
    W: Write,
    ... more bounds,
{ .. impl details .. }


// example usage would be something like:
let list = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
for item in ProgLog::wrap(list, stdout()) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

Essentially just wrapping the given `IntoIterator` with my own `Iterator` implementation that prints out a `.` each time `next()` is called -- easy!

... Until I wanted to differentiate between `Iterator`s and `ExactSizeIterator`s ...

So I added some internal state to my wrapper `Iterator`:

```rust
pub enum State {
    Bounded{
        current_idx: usize,
        max_idx: usize,
    },
    Unbounded{
        current_tick: usize,
    },
}
```

I essentially want to add another implementation of `wrap(..)` that would have an additional trait bound of `T::IntoIter : ExactSizeIterator`, but the compiler wont allow that (as I understand, at least not until 'specialization' gets fully implemented?)...

Then I was looking at how you might differentiate between different traits in a single function (I was hoping there might be some `match` clause for types?), but I haven't found anything there...

Help!  Is there any obvious solution I'm missing that would allow me to setup the internal state as `State::Unbounded` for `Iterators` and `State::Bounded` for `ExactSizeIterator`?

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is possible without specialization, which as you've already pointed out is currently unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution is not possible until specialization (someday...), but fortunately for this specific problem, there's [`size_hint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint) that you can use instead.

```rs
let (min, max) = iter.size_hint();
if Some(min) == max {
    Bounded {
        current_idx: 0,
        max_idx: min,
    }
} else {
    Unbounded {
        current_tick: 0
    }
}
```

`size_hint` returns a lower and upper bound, so if they're the same, you know this is the runtime equivalent of an `ExactSizeIterator`. In addition, `ExactSizeIterator` uses `size_hint` for its default implementation of `len`.

Comment: Thank you! This is an acceptable workaround for the time being, and exactly the kind of thing I was hoping I just missed!  

Just to note though, the `size_hint()` method returns the `max` as `Option<T>` rather than `min` as this example shows.

Comment: @Teknein The example works https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b128ae9d8ec4bf731ed1ecfa5f9c401b